# I can't reinstall my OS X El Capitan. "Please Run Install OS X El Capitan.app"

Tags: terminal, mac, imac, bash, recovery

I'm in recovery mode, but when I try to reinstall the OS this shows to me.

[image]

I've entry to the terminal of Recovery OS. And I found that file .app

[image]

In other forum I found that the solution is move that file to the folder Applications. But I can't. I've tried to copy and move, but nothing happens.

**Trying to copy**

```
cp -R /"Install OS X El Capitan".app /Applications
```

[image]

**Trying to move**

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the following information:  From where and how did you acquire the **Install OS X El Capitain** _application bundle_ and what size is it? How, specifically, did you create the **macOS USB Installer**, did you follow the directions in [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT201372)?

Comment: Why are you trying to move it?  If you’re in recovery mode, you have the option of reinstalling macOS *from the menu.*. This seems like a very convoluted thing going on here.